# Google Tag Manager with Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Recently, Google added **Google Tag Manager** in the Google Play Services ([Google Play services 4.3...](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html)) and I tried to use it to log things in my Universal Analytics account.

I followed [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/), but nothing wanted to work. When I tried to log an event, I got these warnings:

```
GoogleTagManager(3662): Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container
GoogleTagManager(3662): Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
ActivityManager(389): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
GoogleTagManager(3662): Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
ActivityManager(389): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

Has anyone had the same errors and can tell me what the problem is?

**Second question:** Is this possible to deal with Universal Analytics (not Google Analytics) without using Google Tag Manager?

I can log things in a Google Analytics account. But when I change the trackID to an Universal Analytics one, nothing is logged.